# swift programming: string.components(separatedBy: ",")

Tags: swift, performance, split

Swift programming;

I have an array of strings that I split into string pairs of the form

```
var eachpair: [String] = [string1,string2]
```

then I split each pair to single string and convert each string to Float.
I am using the following technique but it takes a huge amount of time to do the splitting. It takes much less time to do this in Java. Is there a way to speed up this process?

```
var var1: Float = Float((eachpair.components(separatedBy: ","))[0])
var var2: Float = Float((eachpair.components(separatedBy: ","))[1])
```

I appreciate all the help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do a little better, with example strings maybe?  It doesn't look like you're using arrays in the best situation.

Comment: It's pretty unclear exactly what you're trying to achieve here – you cannot call `components(seperatedBy:)` on a `[String]`.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup  I am using the XMLparser and obtain coordinates as ["String"]. But the coordinates caontaines multiple (X,Y) pairs separated by space. For instance ["1.0,2.3 4.2,2.3 2.9,5.1]. I need to split this such that I can convert each element to a float. But takes a long time to do this if you use split in a loop. I am looking for some other methods. So the first split is to make each set a pair of strings. this is no problem single command. But when I want to split each pair again with comma, I have to use a loop since there are multiple string pairs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how "slow" it actually could be.  When working with arrays, a loop is very common and trivial.  I don't see why doing the following could be performance impacting unless your initial array is extremely large (500+).

```
 let coords: [String] = ["10.25,23.42","76.21,30.82","71.33,66.34"]
 var floatCoords: [Float]!

 for pairs in coords {
       let temp = Float(pairs.components(seperatedBy: ",")
       floatCoords.append(contentsOf: temp)
 }
```

Comment: There some serious issues with the `let temp = ...` line in this answer. 1) It won't compile. 2) `String components(separatedBy:` returns an `[String]`. You can't create a `Float` from a `[String]`.

Comment: @rmaddy  I did this from the app and I'm still not near my machine, so I was going from memory, but now that I re look at you're correct.  I'll fix it later tonight.  But the idea was to just point him the right direction and answer his _performance issues_ problem.

Comment: I think the biggest performance issue is that the OP needlessly calls `components(separatedBy:` on each value of `eachpair` twice instead of just one.

Comment: Sorry for taking your time with this question. The problem was not related to the code. For some reason when you run this code on playground, it is extremely slow. But when you run it in project as a source file, it is much more faster. I do not know why.